# Why is the CPU time different with every execution of this program?

Tags: c++, performance, clock

I have a hard time understanding processor time. The result of this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

// the function f() does some time-consuming work
void f()
{
    volatile long double d;
    int size = 10000;
    for(int n=0; n<size; ++n)
       for(int m=0; m<size; ++m)
           d = n*m;
}

int main()
{
    std::clock_t start = std::clock();
    f();
    std::clock_t end = std::clock();

    std::cout << "CPU time used: "
              << (end - start)
              << "\n";
}
```

Seems to randomly fluctuate between 210 000, 220 000 and 230 000. At first I was amazed, why these discrete values. Then I found out that `std::clock()` returns only [approximate processor time](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock). So probably the value returned by `std::clock()` is rounded to a multiple of 10 000. This would also explain why the maximum difference between the CPU times is 20 000 (10 000 == rounding error by the first call to `std::clock()` and 10 000 by the second).

But if I change to `int size = 40000;` in the body of `f()`, I get fluctuations in the ranges of 3 400 000 to 3 500 000 which cannot be explained by rounding.

From what I read about the [clock rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit), on Wikipedia:

> The CPU requires a fixed number of clock ticks (or clock cycles) to
>   execute each instruction. The faster the clock, the more instructions
>   the CPU can execute per second.

That is, if the program is deterministic (which I hope mine is), the CPU time needed to finish should be:

1. Always the same
2. Slightly higher than the number of instructions carried out

My experiments show neither, since my program needs to carry out at least `3 * size * size` instructions. Could you please explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The program's results may be deterministic, but its execution time is not, since you probably have other things running on your box.

Comment: your code does not run in perfect isolation with nothing else in the word. In theory, half way through this trivial program all hell could break loose halting execution for a few centuries.

Comment: You have simplistic expectations of how (a) computers and (b) time-shared operating systems work.

Comment: @thecoshman Which shouldn't affect the results of `clock()` (and doesn't on most of the systems I've worked on).

Comment: there are other things running on the system which may not be deterministic

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes the reason I am learning how to use 'clock()' is to be able to compare the execution times of two pieces of code irrespective of all the other things that are happening. I thought that 'clock()' measures the time consumed by a process. That is, if that process is interrupted, 'clock()' should account for that interruption.

Comment: @Chethan Almost nothing on a modern machine is really deterministic.  That's what makes tuning programs so much fun.  You end up with something really fast... except on the day you do the demo in front of your most important customer.

Comment: @Martin It cannot account for everything that happens when your process is interrupted: your process shares resources with other processes on the machine. See James answer below.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit His expectations are justified according to the standard.  At least on older machines, where cache misses don't play a role.

Comment: Also, FWIW: the original implementations of `clock` did return values which incremented by one.  With a `CLOCKS_PER_SECOND` often around 50 or 60.  Somewhere along the line, someone decided that `CLOCKS_PER_SECOND` should be a constant accross lots of machines (Posix requires 1000000).  So modern implementations use so very large values for `CLOCKS_PER_SECOND`, even if it doesn't reflect the granularity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't state what hardware you're running the binary on.

Does it have an interrupt driven CPU ?

Is it a multitasking operating system ?

You're mistaking the cycle time of the CPU (the CPU clock as Wikipedia refers to) with the time it takes to execute a particular piece of code from start to end and all the other stuff the poor CPU has to do at the same time.

Also ... is all your executing code in level 1 cache, or is some in level 2 or in main memory, or on disk ... what about the next time you run it ?

Comment: In theory, `clock()` measures CPU time attributed to the process, so only the cache should be an issue.  (In practice, `clock()` is broken in the Microsoft libraries, and is so unreliable as to be totally worthless.)

Answer (score 8):

First, the statement you quote from Wikipedia is simply false.
It might have been true 20 years ago (but not always, even
then), but it is totally false today.  There are many things
which can affect your timings:

- The first: if you're running on Windows, `clock` is broken,
  and totally unreliable.  It returns the difference in elapsed
  time, not CPU time.  And elapsed time depends on all sorts of
  other things the processor might be doing.
- Beyond that: things like cache misses have a very significant
  impact on time.  And whether a particular piece of data is in
  the cache or not can depend on whether your program was
  interrupted between the last access and this one.

In general, anything less than 10% can easily be due to the
caching issues.  And I've seen differences of a factor of 10
under Windows, depending on whether there was a build running or
not.

Comment: +1... and also in multi-processing operating systems, there is no guarantee to execute `f()` right after previous line `std::clock_t start = std::clock();`.

Comment: @MM. That _shouldn't_ matter, since any intervening time would not be CPU time attributable to your process.  (But it will matter if your implementation of `clock()` is broken.)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, do you know a good alternative to measure time because as you said clock is really broken in practice

Comment: @AbdulRahimHaddad I've never had to do it, but you might look into `GetProcessTimes [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx].

Answer (score 2):

Your program is not deterministic, because it uses library and system functions which are not deterministic.

As a particular example, when you allocate memory this is virtual memory, which must be mapped to physical memory. Although this is a system call, running kernel code, it takes place on your thread and will count against your clock time. How long it takes to do this will depend on what the overall memory allocation situation is.

Answer (score 1):

The CPU time is indeed "fixed" for a given set of circumstances. However, in a modern computer, there are other things happening in the system, which interferes with the execution of your code. It may be that caches are being wiped out when your email software wakes up to check if there is any new emails for you, or when the HP printer software checks for updates, or when the antivirus software decides to run for a little bit checking if your memory contains any viruses, etc, etc, etc, etc.

Part of this is also caused by the problem that CPU time accounting in any system is not 100% accurate - it works on "clock-ticks" and similar things, so the time used by for example an interrupt to service a network packet coming in, or the hard disk servicing interrupt, or the timer interrupt to say "another millisecond ticked by" these all account into "the currently running process". Assuming this is Windows, there is a further "feature", and that is that for historical and other reasons, `std::clock()` simply returns the time now, not actually the time used by your process. So for exampple:

```
t = clock();
cin >> x;
t = clock() - t;
```

would leave `t` with a time of 10 seconds if it took ten seconds to input the value of `x`, even though 9.999 of those ten seconds were spent in the idle process, not your program.

Comment: To quote the C standard: "The clock function returns the implementation’s best approximation to the _processor_
time used by the program[...]" (emphasis added).  The only word that correctly describes the Windows implementation is "broken".

Comment: Yes, it probably is kept that broken way because in the days of DOS and possibly early Windows, code was written using `clock()` to do other timekeeping things, and thus when the code is ported to later version, "we can't allow the code to break..."